# adding arguments to process not working?

Tags: c#, process, arguments

I got this program written in C# WinForms.

im using system.diagnostic to create a CMD process.
with that cmd i want some arguments but they are not present or working :S
dont know why ?!

NOTE: im not sure how to use more than 1 argument, correct me if im wrong :D
im trying to replicate the "copy /b %filename% lpt1" command....

here is my code:

```
    public void OutputBtn_Process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo fi in listBox1.Items)
        {
            Process process1 = new Process();
            process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "copy /b myfile.txt test.txt";
            //process1.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fi.FullName);
            process1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: NOTE: i just added the test.txt instead of LPT1 for testing purpose.

Comment: That's correct, you just need the "/c" as the first parameter.

Comment: Do you actually have FileInfo instances being retrieved from listbox1.Items?

Comment: yeap. so far it works :)
without path.GetdirectoryName it would'nt work sayin something like" path is invalid"

Comment: but that also opens up for my next question. how do I add in my file names into to cmd line ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C \"copy /b myfile.txt LPT1:\"";
```

[The documentation on Windows 7 command-line tool cmd.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ec588db-31a9-4a73-a970-65a2c6f4abbe)

Comment: thanks. it sure did something now. 
the CMD windows pops up quick and closes again saying that LPT1 is not recognize device. but thats probably cause I dont have LPT port in my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "/C copy /b myfile.txt test.txt";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```